# Docker container on host with two NICs connected to internet

Tags: iptables, routing, docker

I'm running a docker container with port 6882 exposed on a host with two NICs. Each NIC is connected to a router with a public IP address.

How can I allow my docker to be reached through both public IPs? Currently it only works with one public IP where the default gateway is connected to.

My docker command something like this:

```
$ docker run <image_name> -p 6882:6882 ...
```

Basically I bind the 6882 to all interfaces.

Actually for the second public IP address, if I'm in the network of the second router I can still reach the container through the second public IP. But if I'm outside, the default gateway doesn't allow the container to return the packets through the second interface.